# form display results on same page + random answer

Tags: javascript

So I have a 3 question "what profession are you quiz"... and after the text, radio and select are chosen and submitted, the results are to show next to them. The text and select do but not the radio. The select shows if I have the radios as, `if ((php.checked==false) && (asp.checked==false) && (js.checked==false)){rad.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");}` ... How my set up is now the text shows but the radio and select dont. Also I need to have an array that holds the solutions and once the answers get submitted, it randomly shows a solution, like "You are a Warrior!". And this is a .PHP extension. Heres my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Ex 2</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
function checkForm(){

    var chk = true;
    var mName = document.getElementById("txtMeth");
    var meth = document.getElementById("methMess");
    var rad = document.getElementById("radMess");
    var sel = document.getElementById("selMess");
    var php = document.getElementById("a");
    var asp = document.getElementById("b");
    var js = document.getElementById("c");
    var arr = document.getElementById("imp");

        mName.style.backgroundColor="#fff";
        meth.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
        rad.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
        sel.setAttribute("style", "display:none");


    if (mName.value=='no'){     
        document.getElementById("methMess").innerHTML = "No";
        meth.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if (mName.value=='yes'){        
        document.getElementById("methMess").innerHTML = "Yes";
        meth.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }       
    if (php.value==A){
        document.getElementById("radMess").innerHTML = "Healer";
        rad.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if (asp.value==B){
        document.getElementById("radMess").innerHTML = "Dark";
        rad.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if (js.value==C){
        document.getElementById("radMess").innerHTML = "One with the Elements";
        rad.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if (arr.value==1){
        document.getElementById("selMess").innerHTML = "Rifle";
        sel.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if (arr.value==2){
        document.getElementById("selMess").innerHTML = "Bown and Arrow";
        sel.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if (arr.value==3){
        document.getElementById("selMess").innerHTML = "Daggers";
        sel.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }

}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="page">   
<main role="main">
<article>
    <div id="errMess" class="errMess">*Required Fields Missing</div>
      <h1>What Guild Wars 2 Profession Are You</h1>

        <div class="cssTable" style="margin-top:-25px;">
        <form method="post">
          <table>
          <tr><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td><div align="right">Do you like to do high damage?</div></td><td width="217">
            <input id="txtMeth" name="txtMeth" type="text" size="25"></td><td ><div id="methMess" style="display:none"></div></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div align="right">What best describes you?</div></td><td>
                <input id="a" type="radio" name = "group1" value="A">Healer</input>
                <input id="b" type="radio" name = "group1" value="B">Dark</input>
                <input id="c" type="radio" name = "group1" value="C">Earthling</input>               
                </td><td><div id="radMess" style="display:none"></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>What weapon would you like to have?</td>
                <td>
                <select id="imp"><option value="0" selected="true">Select One</option>
                <option value="1">Rifle</option>
                <option value="2">Bow and Arrow</option>
                <option value="3">Daggers</option></select>
                </td><td><div id="selMess" style="display:none"></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="3" align="right"><input type="button" class="styled-button-7" value="Send" onclick="checkForm()"/></td></tr></table></form></div></article>
                </main></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `php.value === 'A' || asp.value === 'B' || js.value == 'C'` or do you define those values somewhere else?

Comment: those are the radio, var php id is "a" and its value is "A". Is that what you meaning?

Comment: partly, my problem here would be that A, B, C are not enclosed as a string, you are using them as if they are variables defined somewhere else. If you would like to compare the value of the radioboxes with the string value 'A' then also enclose them as such...

Comment: I did that but it will only display "One with the elements" neither of the other two work, and it does it without being checked.

Comment: our teacher wants us to use js because she hasn't done any jquery with us yet

Answer (score 0):

It is like this that your radio buttons will always have the values 'A', 'B' or 'C', it is simply how you define them in your HTML.

A radiobutton should be checked for active by using the '.checked' property rather than over a value.

Please see the [js fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/9gevc26u/)

and the changes i made to your code are:

I updated your if's

```
if (php.checked) {
    document.getElementById("radMess").innerHTML = "Healer";
    rad.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
    chk = false;
}
if (asp.checked) {
    document.getElementById("radMess").innerHTML = "Dark";
    rad.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
    chk = false;
}
if (js.checked) {
    document.getElementById("radMess").innerHTML = "One with the Elements";
    rad.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
    chk = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So... I had to rename everything because I kept getting confused.  Do not just turn this in or copy it exactly... your teacher will probably know you didn't do it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Ex 2</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style>td { height:25px }</style>
<script>

function checkForm() {

   var high   = document.getElementById('high');      // mName
   var desc   = document.getElementsByName('desc');   // group1
   var weapon = document.getElementById('weapon');    // imp

   // console.log(high);
   // console.log(desc);
   // console.log(weapon);

   // get the checked radio button value to be used later
   var desc_value;  
   for(var i=0; i<desc.length; i++){ 
      if (desc[i].checked) desc_value = desc[i].value;
   }

   var error = false;
   if (!high.value) {
      // if you need to do validation for Yes/No, do it here 
      document.getElementById('errMess').innerHTML = 'high damage missing'; 
      error = true; 
   }
   else if (!desc_value) {
      document.getElementById('errMess').innerHTML = 'desc missing'; 
      error = true; 
   }
   else if (!weapon.value) {
      document.getElementById('errMess').innerHTML = 'weapon missing'; 
      error = true; 
   }

   if (!error) {
      document.getElementById('errMess').innerHTML = ''; 

      // do you like to do high damage?
      high.style.background = '#fff';
      high.style.display    = 'none';
      var highMess = document.getElementById('highMess');
          highMess.innerHTML = high.value;
          highMess.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline');  

      // what best describes you?
      var desc_val;
      var desc_msg = document.getElementById('descMsg');
          desc_msg.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline'); 
          desc_msg.innerHTML = desc_value; 
      for(var i=0; i<desc.length; i++){    
         // loop through the radio button group to hide the parent <span>
         desc[i].parentNode.setAttribute('style', 'display:none'); 
      }

      // what weapon would you like to have? 
      weapon.style.display = 'none';
      var weapon_val = weapon.options[weapon.selectedIndex].value;
      var weapon_msg = document.getElementById('weaponMsg');
          weapon_msg.innerHTML = weapon_val;
          weapon_msg.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline'); 
   }
}

</script>
</head>

<!-- this sets the selected option to being out of range (aka blank/empty) -->    
<body onload="document.getElementById('weapon').selectedIndex = -1;">

<div class="page">
<main role='main'>
<article>
   <div id='errMess' class='errMess' style='font-weight:bold; height:26px'></div>
     <h1>What Guild Wars 2 profession are you.....?</h1>
      <div class='cssTable' style='margin-top:-25px;'>
      <form method='post'>
        <table>
         <tr><td colspan='3'></td></tr>
         <tr>
            <td><div align='right'>Do you like to do high damage?</div></td>
            <td width='217px'><input id='high' name='high' type='text' size='25'/></td>
            <td><div id='highMess' style='display:none'></div></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><div align='right'>What best describes you?</div></td>
            <td>
               <!-- i added spans outside of the <input/> so you could hide the text easily, too -->
               <span><input id='healer'    type='radio' name='desc' value='healer'>Healer</input></span>
               <span><input id='dark'      type='radio' name='desc' value='dark'>Dark</input></span>
               <span><input id='earthling' type='radio' name='desc' value='earthling'>Earthling</input></span>
            </td>
            <td><div id='descMsg' style='display:none'></div></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>What weapon would you like to have?</td>
            <td>
               <select id='weapon' name='weapon'>
                  <option value='rifle'>Rifle</option>
                  <option value='bow_arrow'>Bow and Arrow</option>
                  <option value='daggers'>Daggers</option>
               </select>
            </td>
            <td><div id='weaponMsg' style='display:none'></div></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan='3' align='right'><input type='button' class='styled-button-7' onClick='checkForm()' value='Submit'/></td>
         </tr>
         </table>
      </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</article>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```